# Service crash with Fatal Signal 11 error

Tags: android, android-service, mqtt

I'm using an mqtt server connection in my service which runs continuosly making frequent requests to server.my service crashes suddenly leaving my ui unresponsive, activity crashed but application is not crashed and ondestroy method is not called when service is crashed.
here's logcat when service crashes:

```
10-21 10:34:12.841: W/ActivityThread(10204): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
10-21 10:34:13.561: A/libc(10204): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x003a003d (code=1)
10-21 10:34:18.061: E/PhonePolicy(10577): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
```

here is my service code:

```
package com.voltytrack;

public class SubscribeService extends Service implements MqttCallback {

public static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://27.6.120.57:1883";

String clientId = null;
public  static MqttClient mqttClient = null;

final String ROUTEPOINTSTOPIC = "GPS/DATA/ROUTE";
final String BUSLOCTOPIC = "DEMO/CURRENTLOCATION";
final String GETLISTTOPIC = "GPS/DATA/HISTORY/LIST/"+LoginActivity.deviceid;
final String HISTORYTOPIC = "GPS/DATA/HISTORY/"+LoginActivity.deviceid;
String USERNAME = null, PASSWORD = null;
Intent connectedintent;
static Timer conntimer;
public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MqttService"; // Debug TAG
private static final String MQTT_THREAD_NAME = "MqttService[" + DEBUG_TAG + "]"; // Handler Thread ID
private Handler mConnHandler;     // Seperate Handler thread for networking
HandlerThread hthread = new HandlerThread(MQTT_THREAD_NAME);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(businforeceiver, new IntentFilter("SUBSCRIBERECEIVER"));
    hthread.start();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    long memory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024;
    Log.i("Memory", String.valueOf(memory));
        USERNAME = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        PASSWORD = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    try {

        mConnHandler = new Handler(hthread.getLooper());
        mConnHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            try {
                connectedintent = new Intent("CONNECTED");
                MqttConnectOptions connoptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
                connoptions.setCleanSession(false);
                connoptions.setUserName(USERNAME);
                connoptions.setPassword(PASSWORD.toCharArray());
                connoptions.setConnectionTimeout(10);
                clientId = "and" + Math.random();
                mqttClient = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
                mqttClient.setCallback(SubscribeService.this);
                mqttClient.connect(connoptions);
                if(mqttClient.isConnected()){
                    connectedintent.putExtra("CONN_STATUS", "Connection Successful");
                }
                sendBroadcast(connectedintent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacting Server...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch(MqttSecurityException e) {
                connectedintent.putExtra("CONN_STATUS", "Invalid credentials");
                sendBroadcast(connectedintent);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch(MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                connectedintent.putExtra("CONN_STATUS", "Connection failed");
                sendBroadcast(connectedintent);
//                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("not connected", e.getMessage());
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error, Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(businforeceiver);
    try {
//          mqttClient.unsubscribe(TOPIC);
        if(mqttClient.isConnected()){
            mqttClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 super.onDestroy();
}
public BroadcastReceiver businforeceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String PUBLISHTOPIC = intent.getExtras().getString("PUBLISHTOPIC");
        String SUBSCRIBETOPIC = intent.getExtras().getString("SUBSCRIBETOPIC");
        String DATA = intent.getExtras().getString("TRAVERSE");

        try {

            if(null!=SUBSCRIBETOPIC){
                String[] topic = SUBSCRIBETOPIC.split("@");
                mqttClient.subscribe(topic[0]);
                mqttClient.subscribe(topic[1]);
            }
            if(null != PUBLISHTOPIC){
                MqttMessage msg1 = new MqttMessage();
                msg1.setPayload(DATA.getBytes());
                msg1.setQos(0);
                mqttClient.getTopic(PUBLISHTOPIC).publish(msg1);
            }
        } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
            Log.e("BROADCAST SERVICE", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e("BROADCAST SERVICE", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
    try {

        if(null!=conntimer){
            conntimer.cancel();
        }

        MqttConnectOptions connoptions1 = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connoptions1.setCleanSession(false);
        connoptions1.setUserName(USERNAME);                            
        connoptions1.setPassword(PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        mqttClient = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
        mqttClient.setCallback(SubscribeService.this);
        mqttClient.connect(connoptions1);
        if(mqttClient.isConnected()){

            mqttClient.subscribe(BUSLOCTOPIC);
            mqttClient.subscribe(HISTORYTOPIC);
            Log.i("conn_status", "connected");
        }
        else{
            Log.i("conn_status", "not connected");
        }

    } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        conntimer = new Timer();
        conntimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                connectionLost(null);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("not connected", e.getMessage());
    } 
}
@Override
public void deliveryComplete(MqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void messageArrived(MqttTopic arg0, MqttMessage arg1)
        throws Exception {
    if(GETLISTTOPIC.matches(arg0.toString())){
        Intent busdataintent = new Intent("BUSLIST");
        busdataintent.putExtra("buslist", arg1.toString());
        sendBroadcast(busdataintent);
    }
    else if(HISTORYTOPIC.matches(arg0.toString())){
        Intent buspointsintent = new Intent("BUSPOINTS");
        buspointsintent.putExtra("buspoints", arg1.toString());
        sendBroadcast(buspointsintent);
    }
    else if(ROUTEPOINTSTOPIC.matches(arg0.toString())){
        Intent userbusintent = new Intent("USERBUSDATA");
        userbusintent.putExtra("boardingpoints", arg1.toString());
        sendBroadcast(userbusintent);

    }

}

}
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: This may be because you are making the connection in UI thread... Make it in background thread asynchronously.

Comment: I've done connection in another thread only using handler, please check the service code above.

Comment: You are using mConnHandler.post which post the results in Main UI Thread

Comment: ok i've done as u said, created new thread.. but still getting same error and crashing..